# Switzerland's Customs: Will they accept items from TCM (Chinese Medicine)?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, switzerland

Chinese Medicine (or Traditional Chinese Medicine, TCM for short) is mostly made up of herbal stuff made-up of:

[Wikipedia: TCM Herbal Medicine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_Chinese_medicine#Herbal_medicine)

- dried plant(s)
- dried animal parts
- herbs
- plant elements
- plant extracts

If going through customs bringing a bunch of different (TCM) herbs, separately (i.e.: a bag of ginseng, a bag of licorice, a bag of ginger, a bag of Goji berries), would there be any problems?

What is the proper way to deal with these kind of *herbs* (or plant/plant extracts) whilst going through customs?

Some things are plant-related, would that be cause for concern?

---

just for clarification the question is just related to herbs and plants not including thing like: dried curled snakes, dried seahorses, human penises or flying squirrel feces: as per [Wikipedia's list of TCMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_traditional_Chinese_medicines)....

Comment: What country's customs and immigration would you be attempting to pass?

Comment: @CGCampbell Switzerland.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switzerland’s restrictions on the import of plants are outlined here:
[Swiss Customs Administration – Plants, cut flowers and protection of species (CITES)](http://www.ezv.admin.ch/zollinfo_privat/04406/04413/index.html?lang=en)

There is some more detailed information regarding the import of medicinal plants on the Web site of the Federal Food Safety and Veterinary Office, but only in [German](http://www.blv.admin.ch/themen/handel_wild/05116/05169/index.html?lang=de), [French](http://www.blv.admin.ch/themen/handel_wild/05116/05169/index.html?lang=fr) and [Italian](http://www.blv.admin.ch/themen/handel_wild/05116/05169/index.html?lang=it).

Some species cannot be imported for reasons of bio-security, while others may be permitted but must be inspected. Otherwise, Switzerland is a member of the Convention on International Trade in Endangered Species of Wild Fauna and Flora ([CITES](http://www.cites.org/)), which publishes a [long list](http://www.cites.org/eng/app/appendices.php) of species in which trade is restricted and for which import and/or export permits are required.

Of the plants you listed, ginseng root is in CITES Appendix II and requires an import permit (though powders and other derivatives are exempt); the others are not mentioned.

Comment: Would it be a safe bet to say that: if everything was already made into a powder, there wouldn't be much of a problem?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be a safe assumption. There are many banned substances in powder form. How would customs tell yours apart? Commercial packaging with a description of the ingredients helps, but probably less so if that description is in Chinese.